# How to disable onclick on whole row if user clicks on a collapse button on that row?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I prevent that `window.location` from invoking after clicking on button?

```
<tr onclick="window.location='www.google.com'">

    <td>Toggle Button</td>

    <td style="text-align:left;">

        <button class="btn btn-link text-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#company@item.Id">
            Details
        </button>

        <div id="myitems5" class="collapse">
            items
            items
            items
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The best way to prevent `onclick` from invoking is to understand what exactly [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) do. If you need to invoke a website, use `<a href="www.google.com">click me</a>`.

Comment: @hcheung - Except of course, you can't wrap a link around a table row. (In the general case, I strongly agree that using links rather than faking them is better, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, but I'm not suggesting that.

Comment: @hcheung - You're suggesting having a link in one of the cells? Rather changes the UX (but improves accessibility, open in new window, ...). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh please, the OP not mentioned anything of UX, nor providing any JS code. I'm merely trying to provide a direction and hoping for some clarification on OP's clarification.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my apology for misunderstood your intention and the signs at the end of your msgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal-changes way would be this:

```
<tr onclick="if (!event.target.closest('button[data-toggle]')) { window.location = '//www.google.com'; }">
```

...which says that if the event passed through a `button` with a `data-toggle` attribute en route to the `tr`, you don't do anything, but if it did you do the `window.location` thing (note the fix on the string there).

But I wouldn't do it that way. I'd use a proper event handler, probably a delegated one of the table, and do the check in that event handler.

For instance:

```
theTable.addEventListener(function(e) {
    var tr = e.target.closest("tr");
    if (tr && this.contains(tr)) {
        var btn = e.target.closest("button[data-toggle]");
        if (!btn || !tr.contains(btn)) {
            window.location = "//www.google.com";
        }
    }
});
```

---

In both cases, the code makes use of [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which you may need to polyfill on outdated browsers.